# Union and intersection operations on collections in Cypher (Neo4j)

Tags: collections, neo4j, union, cypher, intersection

I need to calculate both the union and the intersection of a set of arrays/collections in Cypher. Let's say for instance I have the topics of interest of a number of individuals saved as array properties for each individual node and I need to know (1) the topics that every member of a given group find interesting; but I also need to know (2) the topics that may attract the attention of any of the group members.

So, take the following individuals as the members of a group of two:

```
CREATE ({name: 'bill', interests: ["biking", "hiking", "fishing", "swimming"]})
CREATE ({name: 'joe', interests: ["swimming", "hiking", "biking", "tennis"]})
```

Inspired by [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20483117/1840412) I have written the following scripts to get what I need:

**Intersection (n.interests ∩ m.interests)**

```
MATCH (n {name:'bill'}), (m {name:'joe'})
RETURN FILTER(x IN n.interests WHERE x IN m.interests)
```

*Response: biking, hiking, swimming*

**Union (n.interests ∪ m.interests)**

```
MATCH (n {name:'bill'}), (m {name:'joe'})
RETURN FILTER(x IN n.interests WHERE x IN m.interests)+
FILTER(x IN n.interests WHERE NOT(x IN m.interests))+
FILTER(x IN m.interests WHERE NOT(x IN n.interests))
```

*Response: biking, hiking, swimming, fishing, tennis*

Both work pretty well for groups of two. The problem is the union script is not generalizable and needs to be expanded further for each additional group member. This is because instead of doing a straightforward `n.interests ∪ m.interests` I am going the long way by producing `(n.interests ∩ m.interests) ∪ (n.interests - m.interests) ∪ (m.interests - n.interests)` which equals `n.interests ∪ m.interests`, but necessitates pairwise comparison of all individuals in the group.

Hence my question: Is there any better way in Cypher to produce the union of two collections/arrays, without redundant results in the response collection?

P.S. As you may have noticed these interests don't really have an ordering, so I am actually treating Neo4j collections as sets.

P.S.2 It is possible that I am misunderstanding and incorrectly conflating the notions of collection and array in Cypher, in which case please don't hesitate to point out what the mistake is.

Comment: not really related to your question: why don't you model the interests as nodes and have explicit relationships to them instead of hiding the structure in an array property?

Comment: This was just a simplified example, but to answer your question: because in my application these properties are mostly dead data, meaning that I rarely access them. So, I am trying to keep the database schema from unneeded growth and complexity. These will be nodes with one property each, and sometimes there are hundreds of them per individual, and they serve very little purpose.

Answer (score 3):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) has union and intersection functions, should be exactly what you need.

```
MATCH (n {name:'bill'}), (m {name:'joe'})
RETURN apoc.coll.union(n.interests, m.interests) as interests_union,
       apoc.coll.intersection(n.interests, m.interests) as interests_intersection
```

The above is usable with Neo4j 3.1 and up (which supports user-defined functions). In Neo4j 3.0, these are procedures instead, and you'll need to CALL them as procedures.

This is also easily applied to multiple collections, instead of just two. If the collections are collected, you can run REDUCE() on the list of lists to apply the union or intersection for all collections.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can generalize it using `reduce` to produce your collections.

And probably use one of the quantor-predicates (ANY,ALL, SINGLE, NONE)

Something like this for intersection:

```
WITH [1,2,3] as a, [3,4,5] as b, [2,3,4] as c
REDUCE (res=[], x in a | case when x in b AND x in c then res + [x] else res)

WITH [1,2,3] as a, [3,4,5] as b, [2,3,4] as c
REDUCE (res=[], x in a | case when ALL(coll in [b,c] WHERE x in coll) then res + [x] else res)
```

But all of these operations won't have really good runtime characteristics.

Comment: As I said, intersection is easily generalizable. The problem is with Union, because currently there is no way to treat already existing collections as sets in Cypher. A set, as opposed to a collection, would automatically discard duplicates. In such a case a + b + c would return a ∪ b ∪ c when treated as a set.

Answer (score 1):

I recently solved the same problem by first taking the duplicated union, and then deduplicating using `distinct`

```
MATCH (n {name:'bill'}), (m {name:'joe'})
UNWIND n.interests + m.interests AS interests
RETURN COLLECT(distinct interests) AS interests_union
```